# How to pass @Input String in a task in buildSrc

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, buildsrc

This custom plugin exists in gradle's `buildSrc/`:

```kotlin
abstract class MyTask : DefaultTask() {

    @get:Input
    abstract val buildDir: Property<String>

    @TaskAction
    fun someTask() {
       // do stuff
    }
}

class DevelopmentPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.tasks.run {
            register("myTask", MyTask::class.java) {

                inputs.property("buildDir", project.buildDir)

                println(inputs.getProperties())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and by running the task with e.g. `$ ./gradlew myTask` fails with:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':myTask'.
> Cannot query the value of task ':myTask' property 'rootDir' because it has no value available.
```

Also the prinln outputs `{buildDir=null}` meaning that the `inputs.property("buildDir", project.buildDir)` has failed.

---

How to pass the `project.buildDir` value from the Plugin in the task?

Using `project.buildDir` directly from inside the task is not an acceptable answer due to Gradle's [incubating build-cache functionality](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:use_project_during_execution).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @FranciscoMateo What I ask above :) To pass the `project.buildDir` value from the Plugin in the task (and use it in `someTask`).

Comment: I understand, but why? What are you trying to achieve or what is the use case

Comment: Read or write files under `buildDir/somePath/somefile.txt`. The rest is getting out of scope from this very problem.
The task should be runnable by both top-level Gradle module and/or submodules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is a class type issue which is not visible in Gradle.

buildDir is of type `File` while the property is `String`.

So `"${project.buildDir}"` should be used.

Secondly, since the property is `abstract val` it can directly be accessed in the closure. Therefore it can be set with:

```kotlin
// instead of:
inputs.property("buildDir", "${project.buildDir}")
// just this:
buildDir.set("${project.buildDir}")
```